# Determinate shift by X-axis of css objects, javascript

Tags: javascript, css, math, geometry, drawing

I'm trying to draw something like STAR  `*`.

https://jsfiddle.net/jsfiddlefcn/w7y86acz/7/

From the center `width / 2` and `height / 2` to different points around `bx` and `by`.

```
var counter = 0;

function linedraw(ax, ay, bx, by) {
  var r = parseInt(Math.random() * 255);
  var g = parseInt(Math.random() * 255);
  var b = parseInt(Math.random() * 255);
  var a = 0.45;
  var caty = Math.abs(ay - by);
  var catx = Math.abs(ax - bx);
  counter++;
  /*
  $("<div id='catx" + counter + "'>").css({ // optional.
    "height": '2px',
    "background": 'rgba(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ',' + a + ')',
    "width": catx,
    "position": "absolute",
    "top": by,
    "left": Math.min(ax, bx),
    // "transform": "rotate("+rotation+"deg)"
  }).appendTo("#body");
  $("<div id='caty" + counter + "'>").css({ // optional.
    "height": '2px',
    "background": 'rgba(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ',' + a + ')',
    "width": caty,
    "position": "absolute",
    "top": Math.min(ay, by) + caty / 2,
    "left": bx - caty / 2,
    "transform": "rotate(90deg)"
  }).appendTo("#body");*/
  var width = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(catx, 2) + Math.pow(caty, 2));
  var atan = Math.atan( (ay-by) / (ax - bx) );
  //var acos = Math.acos(caty / width);
  //var asin = Math.asin(catx / width);
  var rotation = atan * 360 / ( 2 * Math.PI );
  //var rotation = acos * 360 / ( 2 * Math.PI );
  //var rotation = asin * 360 / ( 2 * Math.PI );
  var Y = Math.min(ay, by) + caty / 2;
  var X = Math.min(ax, bx);
  $("<div id='diagonal_" + counter + "'>").css({ // Main Line
    "height": '2px',
    "background": 'rgba(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ',' + a + ')',
    "width": width,
    "position": "absolute",
    "top": Y,
    "left": X,
    "transform": "rotate(" + rotation + "deg)"
  }).appendTo("#body");
}

var height = 500;
var width = 500;
var step = 30;
for (var x = 0; x < width; x += step) {
  for (var y = 0; y < height; y += step) {
    linedraw(width / 2, height / 2, x, y);
  }
}
```

**`rotation` and `Y` - are correct!**

Need to determinate shift by X-axis.

Variable

```
"left": X,
```

All lines shifted a little bit to the right, depending to the angle with X-axis. Than more angle - the more UNKNOWN shift by X-axis.

[JPEG example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMb8V.jpg)

Comment: Can you further clarify what you mean by Triangles? What triangles? How do you propose to make a star out of triangles... Perhaps include a rough image of what you are hoping to achieve?

Comment: Can you confirm, is it clear?

Comment: Sorry. I still don't understand how you are making a star out of that.

Comment: It is not a Star like `⁕` `✫` `✬` `✭` `✮` `✯` `✰`. It is more like `⨉` over `+` over `╱` over `╲` over `╳` etc, with little step.

Comment: @rasmeister, Please, check the update.  https://jsfiddle.net/jsfiddlefcn/w7y86acz/6/. Why does my lines shifted to the right??? it is must be strange.

Comment: @rasmeister, I'd uploaded Picture!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx to @TicTacVengria from [ru.stackoverflow.com](https://ru.stackoverflow.com//questions/638143/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%A5-css-js-5-%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Right shift is calculated by this way:

```
if (bx > ax)
  var X = ax - width/2 + catx/2;
  else
  var X = ax - width/2 - catx/2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a transform, there is no strange math you need to do. The only challenge is figuring out how to set the angle to match your increments.

For example, I've replaced the latter part of your linedraw code with the following snippet:

```
    var maxX = ax * 2;
    var angleX = bx / maxX * 360;
    $("<div id='diagonal_" + counter + "'>").css({
        "height": '2px',
        "background": 'rgba(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ',' + a + ')',
        "width": 150,
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": 250 - 150 / 2,
        "left": 250 - 150 / 2,
        "transform": "rotate(" + angleX + "deg)"
    }).appendTo("#body");
```

What this does is determines how much of an angle to increment for each step. This is calculated on the knowledge that a circle is 360 degrees. Then you just plug this into your new div's css and you get a star.

You will need to play with the positioning of the center and how long you want each line but, after all, it is your assignment and don't want to do everything for you :-)...

Here's some working code:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="body"></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var counter = 0;

        function linedraw(ax, ay, bx, by) {
            var r = parseInt(Math.random() * 255);
            var g = parseInt(Math.random() * 255);
            var b = parseInt(Math.random() * 255);
            var a = 0.45;
            var caty = Math.abs(ay - by);
            var catx = Math.abs(ax - bx);
            counter++;
            $("<div id='catx" + counter + "'>").css({ // good.
                "height": '2px',
                "background": 'rgba(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ',' + a + ')',
                "width": catx,
                "position": "absolute",
                "top": by,
                "left": Math.min(ax, bx),
                // "transform": "rotate("+rotation+"deg)"
            }).appendTo("#body");
            $("<div id='caty" + counter + "'>").css({ // good.
                "height": '2px',
                "background": 'rgba(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ',' + a + ')',
                "width": caty,
                "position": "absolute",
                "top": Math.min(ay, by) + caty / 2,
                "left": bx - caty / 2,
                "transform": "rotate(90deg)"
            }).appendTo("#body");
            var maxX = ax * 2;
            var angleX = bx / maxX * 360;
            $("<div id='diagonal_" + counter + "'>").css({
                "height": '2px',
                "background": 'rgba(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ',' + a + ')',
                "width": 150,
                "position": "absolute",
                "top": 250 - 150 / 2,
                "left": 250 - 150 / 2,
                "transform": "rotate(" + angleX + "deg)"
            }).appendTo("#body");
        }

        var height = 500;
        var width = 500;
        var step = 30;
        for (var x = 0; x < width; x += step) {
            for (var y = 0; y < height; y += step) {
                linedraw(width / 2, height / 2, x, y);
            }
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Some other comments:

If you are going to do step increments, then I would make sure I reach the target with a whole step rather than partial. So, bump your height and width to 510 (a multiple of 30) or change your step to 25 (since 500 is a multiple of 25).

I would also consider separating out the three things you are doing into separate functions - one for vertical lines, one for horizontal lines and one for your star (diagonal lines).

Comment: Glad to see your answer, but this is not exactly what I'm looking for. Triangles ( one color ) must be closed.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question then, because it is not at all clear what you are looking for.

Comment: Updated. Thank you for helping! I'm sure it is clear from function `linedraw(ax, ay, bx, by)`. Line must depend from `ax`, `ay`, `bx` and `by`.